# Divide Bootstrap 4 div into 2 parts

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to accomplish what has been straightforward in the world of pixels before I jumped into a responsive design. I'm using bootstrap 4 and want a very simple layout. It is comprised of

```
navbar
   main container-fluid div
      div using 85% of main div
      div using 15% of main div
```

I've found lots of examples showing how simple this is, but it just isn't working for me. Here's my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-col" id="mainWindow" >

    <!-- div container for the map. -->
    <div class="row h-75" style="background-color: yellow;">
            map<br>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-25" style="background-color: green;">
            chat<br>
    </div>

</div> <!-- mainWindow -->
```

But what I see is

```
navbar
```

[image]

No yellow div and a small piece of the green div

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Please read the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this you want ??**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
  <div class="row h-75" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="col-12">map</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-25" style="background-color: green;">
    <div class="col-12">chat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I'm looking for two full width rows, one 75% of the viewport height and the second 25% of the height.

Comment: You should never have content directly in a row. The row should always contain at least one `col`!

Comment: It was the html 100% that was messing everything up. Once I added that css style it now works perfectly! Thanks!